# Many Inserts in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am part of one development team, where i have an stored procedure (SQL Server 2008) which contains around 40 insert queries. These queries inserts around at least 100's of records are inserted at every insert operations.

This is impacting the performance of application, though I have set NO count to null and wrapped code in `Begin` and `End transaction`. But, still performance not upto mark, as such it is taking around 2-3 minutes, while our performance requirement is around 10-11 sec.

I can understand these many insertions needded to be reduced but, changing database structure at this moment is quite costly.

Is there any way by which we can execute these insert queries within 10-11 seconds?

Sometimes I wonders that in many sites I have read that SQL Server can perform aroud 1000-2000qps then why my stored procedure taking so long time.

Comment: is 100 record insert only on one table.. every time..?

Comment: yes, but sometimes more than 100 on every inserts

Comment: Not going deep in Stored proc or table structure, I feel this is really structured badly. 
40 insert queries, its really bad. Salute to the person who created it. Sorry if it's you.

Comment: Why do you think NOCOUNT and TRANSACTION increases performance? Are you sure it is the inserts that are slow? Are you using dynamic sql to create the insert statements?

Comment: Are you inserting these records in a set-based fashion or using a cursor or while loop?

Comment: @adrianm actually to make stored procedure atomic we have used transaction, and we have used NOCOUNT so that un-necessarily , procedure don't count number of rows returned in the select or insert query.

while there is cursor which is used, which selects number of rows from table and update the another table's rows accordingly.

Comment: @HLGEM these insert queries are independently applied on each tables such as INSERT-SELECT Query.

Comment: @Nipun Ambastha, Sorry it is not created by me. I know it is really badly structured but, it contains really large amount of data to migrate.

Comment: @SrujalKachhela hmm, I understand your issue. Most of the things stated will minimize issue a little bit however you will still be in problem. 
Possible solutions:
1. Try all things which are stated by great peoples here
2. Enhance Server configuration
3. Try to restructure DB (I know its costly but would help in longer run, client would understand if you will try to make them understand)

Answer (score 0):

If you have indexes on this table, it can be costly to do a lot of inserts. Therefore I would start by examining the tables indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons that can slow things down:

1. Existence of INSERT TRIGGERs on the table
2. Lots of enforced constraints that have to be checked (usually foreign keys)
3. Page splits in the clustered index when a row is inserted in the middle
   of the table
4. Updating all the related non-clustered indexes
5. Blocking from other activity on the table

Have a look at your structure and tell us what can be changed and what not. Without any code we cannot reduce the number of inserts, we can only tell you what could possibly slow things down.

Comment: and i have not manipulated anny index of tables, 
they are as it is when they were created with table.

Comment: Ok, that's a little more clear, can you post your stored procedure, so we can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

please Check this Sample SP

you need to create XML for each row same like below format and give to SQL..

Some modification as per your requirement may be solve your problem..

```
/**************************************************************

EXEC wa_TempInsert '<SampleXML>
<tblRow><Id>3</Id><Code>11</Code><Description>Leptospiral infect NEC</Description></tblRow>
<tblRow><Id>3</Id><Code>22</Code><Description>Leptospiral infect NEC</Description></tblRow>
<tblRow><Id>3</Id><Code>33</Code><Description>Leptospiral infect NEC</Description></tblRow>
<tblRow><Id>3</Id><Code>44</Code><Description>Leptospiral infect NEC</Description></tblRow>
<tblRow><Id>3</Id><Code>55</Code><Description>Leptospiral infect NEC</Description></tblRow>
</SampleXML>'
*/
CREATE PROCEDURE  wa_TempInsert
(   
    @XML NVARCHAR(MAX)  
)  
AS  
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN

    DECLARE @Id INT
    DECLARE @MyXML XML
    SET @MyXML = @XML  

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempXMLTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempICD 

    SELECT * INTO #TempICD 
    FROM (
           SELECT
               Parse.value('(Id)[1]', 'INT') AS 'Id',
               Parse.value('(Code)[1]', 'Varchar(100)') AS 'Code',
               Parse.value('(Description)[1]', 'varchar(1000)') AS 'Description'
            FROM
               @MyXML.nodes('/SampleXML/tblRow') AS TempData(Parse) 
          ) AS tbl





     INSERT INTO Table (Code,[Description],Id)
     SELECT DISTINCT Code,[Description],Id FROM  #TempXMLTable
  END
END
```

Comment: how can this help me improve performance, as such this will keep number of insert queries that are required as it is.

Comment: let say 1000 record in your XML...here you need to parse XMl and create Temp table with tahat 1000 records instead of creating 1000 insert query you need to write only one insert query for that Temp table Which is describe above Example...You don't need to create 1000 time connection with sql... hope this things help you...